# pyecharts- Change dataView language to English

Tags: python, graph, charts, interactive

How to change pyecharts dataview text and buttons from Chinese language to English?[header and the 2 red buttons are on Chinese language.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeSe3.png)

here is the code I used:

line_chart_Traffic_Vol_DL = 
Line().add_xaxis(df3.Date.tolist()).add_yaxis(
'Traffic_Vol_DL',
df3['Traffic_Vol_DL'].tolist(),
is_smooth=True,
is_connect_nones=True,
linestyle_opts=opts.LineStyleOpts(color='blue', width=1),
markline_opts=opts.MarkLineOpts(data=[opts.MarkLineItem(type_='average'
)]),
markpoint_opts=opts.MarkPointOpts(data=[opts.MarkPointItem(type_='max'
, name='Max'), opts.MarkPointItem(type_='min', name='Min'
)]),
).set_series_opts(areastyle_opts=opts.AreaStyleOpts(opacity=0.05,
color='#c6f'),
label_opts=opts.LabelOpts(is_show=False)).set_global_opts(title_opts=opts.TitleOpts(title='Traffic_Vol_DL'
, subtitle='GB'), datazoom_opts=[opts.DataZoomOpts(),
opts.DataZoomOpts(type_='inside')],
tooltip_opts=opts.TooltipOpts(trigger='axis'),
legend_opts=opts.LegendOpts(is_show=False),
toolbox_opts=opts.ToolboxOpts(is_show=True,
feature={'restore': {'title': 'Restore'},
'saveAsImage': {'title': 'Save'},
'dataView': {'title': 'data view'}}))  #     datazoom_opts=opts.DataZoomOpts(orient="vertical"),
#                 "dataZoom": {"yAxisIndex": "none"},

Change the language from Chinese to English on the 2 red buttons and the header

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the language from Chinese to English, here is what I did, I changed the `set_global_opts` as follows:

```
LineChart.set_global_opts(
        title_opts=opts.TitleOpts(title="Line Chart", subtitle="Subtitle"),
        toolbox_opts=opts.ToolboxOpts(
            feature=opts.ToolBoxFeatureOpts(
                save_as_image=opts.ToolBoxFeatureSaveAsImageOpts(title="Download as Image"),
                restore=opts.ToolBoxFeatureRestoreOpts(title="Restore"),
                data_view=opts.ToolBoxFeatureDataViewOpts(title="View Data", lang=["Data View", "Close", "Refresh"]),
                data_zoom=opts.ToolBoxFeatureDataZoomOpts(zoom_title="Zoom In",back_title="Zoom Out")
            
        )
    )
)
```

Under the specified option, look for 'title' and that is where you can change the text when hovered over to match what you would like.
[PyeCharts GlobalOpts](https://github.com/pyecharts/pyecharts/blob/master/pyecharts/options/global_options.py)